# how to find a closed form expression for a power series

Tags: calculus

my question is how do i find a closed form expression for a function f(x) which the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2n(-7)^n x^{n+2}$ converges to and the value of x for which f(x) equals the given power series.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty2n(-7)^nx^{n+2}=2x^2(-7x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-7x)^{n-1}$$

Now, $nx^{n-1}=\dfrac{d(x^n)}{dx}$

See also : [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms)